# Groupby and count occurence frequence in percentage with R

Tags: r

Given a dataset as follows:

```
  city type
0   bj    a
1   bj    a
2   bj    b
3   bj    c
4   sh    a
5   sh    b
6   sh    c
7   sh    c
8   sh    a
```

I need to groupby `city` and `type`, then calculate percentage of occurence frequence for each `type`, which means the sum of percent for each `city` should be `1`.

I have tried with the following code, but it seems the sum of percent of all city's type is `1`.

```
df1 %>%
filter(!is.na(city) & !is.na(type)) %>%
group_by(city, type) %>%
summarise(count = n() / nrow(.))
```

The expected result will like this:

```
  city type  percent
0   bj    a     0.50  ---> 2/4
1   bj    b     0.25  ---> 1/4
2   bj    c     0.25  ---> 1/4
3   sh    a     0.40  ---> 2/5
4   sh    b     0.20  ---> 1/5
5   sh    c     0.40  ---> 2/5
```

How could I do that based on code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `count` and then calculate ratio for each `city` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  na.omit() %>% #Drop NA rows
  count(city, type) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n))

# city  type      n
# <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 bj    a      0.5 
#2 bj    b      0.25
#3 bj    c      0.25
#4 sh    a      0.4 
#5 sh    b      0.2 
#6 sh    c      0.4
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we add `type` in the result?

Comment: Missed that. We can use `mutate`, updated the answer.